# Woocomerce product variation images clickable and change variation attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am using below code to show all products variations images below product main image. Can any one help to make each image clickable and show that in product main image place and also the respective variation attribute to be selected automatically on image click.

I tried below code to display all variations images, but not able to make the images clickable and show in   main product image and dont know how to make the attribute selected on dropdown after variation image clicked.

```
`
```

// Get all variation images from a variable product
function get_variation_images($product_id) {

```
 $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

// Check if the product is variable
  if ($product && $product->is_type('variable')) {
    $variation_images = array();

    // Get variations
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    foreach ($variations as $variation) {
        // Get variation image ID
        $variation_image_id = $variation['image_id'];

        // Get variation image URL
        $variation_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($variation_image_id);

        // Add variation image URL to the array
        $variation_images[] = $variation_image_url;
    }

    return $variation_images;
}

return array();
```

}

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_slick_slider');
```

function enqueue_slick_slider() {
// Enqueue Slick Slider CSS
wp_enqueue_style('slick-css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css');

```
// Enqueue Slick Slider Theme CSS
wp_enqueue_style('slick-theme-css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css');

// Enqueue jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/slider.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

// Enqueue Slick Slider JS
wp_enqueue_script('slick-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
```

}

add_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'output_variation_images_slider', 1);
function output_variation_images_slider() {

```
global $product;

// Check if the product is variable
if ($product && $product->is_type('variable')) {

    $variation_images = get_variation_images($product->get_id());

    // Output the slider container
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-variation-images">';

    // Output each variation image as a slide
    foreach ($variation_images as $image_url) {
    
        echo '<div><img src="' . esc_url($image_url) . '" alt="Variation Image"></div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

}
`